# Adobe DTM Rule not firing based on Regex but Regex test works?

Tags: regex, adobe, adobe-analytics

I have three rules **set-up in a page load rule as regexs** to serve Adobe Target (which is set-up as a tool within DTM) code through DTM.

```
Rule 1 - Path > Include > (small-business.html)
Rule 2 - Path > Include > (commercial-banking.html)
Rule 3 - Path > include > ^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/|\?.+\=.+)?(\?.+\=.+)?$
```

The third rule is to test for the homepage only with/without query string. Either condition is fine. If I put various versions of the homepage URL in the the regex tester provided within DTM or any other online versions, it works fine. The issue is when I run the code on the website, the rule is not firing for the home page? The first two rules work fine. Does anyone know if there is something specific to DTM that is a known issue with this or am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to test for the homepage only (with/without query string)?

Comment: `path` is matched against `location.pathname` which does not include protocol, domain, or port

Comment: Try something like path > include (regex) >  `^\/?(\?.*)?$` This assumes (using full url for context) `http://www.yourdomain.com`  `http://www.yourdomain.com/` `http://www.yourdomain.com?foo=bar` `http://www.yourdomain.com/?foo=bar`